# Flexible placement of labels in seaborn barplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to place labels on bars in Seaborn depending on how much space there is available.

For example in the example below I would like to use *outside labels* if they fit on the figure and *inside labels* when they don't. I would like to do this automatically for many plots, so I am looking for a smart way to do this flexibly. Any ideas?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
titanic=sns.load_dataset('titanic')
titanic.head()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(
    y='sex',
    data=titanic,
    orient="h",
    ax=ax
)
for p in ax.patches:
    perc = "{:.1f}%".format(100 * p.get_width() / titanic.shape[0])
    x = p.get_width()
    y = p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 2
    # inside labels
    ax.annotate(perc, (x*0.8, y), color="white")
    # outside labels
    ax.annotate(perc, (x*1.1, y), color="black")
```

Bad quality example of what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: `ax.margins(x=0.15)` would give enough space to consistently have the labels outside. BTW for your inside label you could try `ha='right'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(
    y='sex',
    data=titanic,
    orient="h",
    ax=ax
    )

values = []
for p in ax.patches:
    
    x = p.get_width() # counts; dimension of the bar
    y = p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 2
    values.append(x) #collect the bar sizes in a list
    x_max = max(values)   #determine the largest bar size
    
#adjust percentage of the maximum bar size where inside/outside annotation occurs
cut_off = 0.8*x_max

for p in ax.patches:
    perc = "{:.1f}%".format(100 * p.get_width() / titanic.shape[0]) #the label for the bar
    x = p.get_width()
    y = p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 2
    
    if x >= cut_off:
        ax.annotate(perc, (x*0.8, y), color="white") 
    else: 
        ax.annotate(perc, (x*1.1, y), color="black")
```

[image: Output looks like this:]